# Pandas: Copy column-wise values to rows in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this data:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    "id": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    "col_to_fill": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df

    id  col_to_fill
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   0
5   2   0
6   2   0
7   2   0
8   2   0
9   2   0
10  3   0
11  3   0
12  3   0
13  3   0
14  3   0  



d1 = {
    "id": [1, 2, 3],
    "val1": [23, 23, 0],
    "val2": [42, 44, 9],
    "val3": [12, 8, 55],
    "val4": [2, 88, 21],
    "val5": [53, 2, 33]
}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(d1)

df2

   id   val1    val2    val3    val4    val5
0   1   23  42  12  2   53
1   2   23  44  8   88  2
2   3   0   9   55  21  33
```

In df I have rows with IDs that are duplicated down N times for each unique ID (N=5 in this case but want it to work for 21 in the real use case, or any if possible).

in df2 I have the same unique IDs in col 1, and some values column-wise (val1, val2, etc.)

Goal:

- I want to have val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 down in each row in df for each instrument.

For ID 1 and 2:

```
id  col_to_fill
1   23
1   42
1   12
1   2
1   53
2   23
2   44
2   8
2   88
2   2
```

And so on
......

This won't work:

`df2.melt(id_vars=['id'])`

Because that will be

```
id  variable
1   val1
1   val1
1   val1
1   val1
1   val1
2   val2
2   val2
2   val2
2   val2
2   val2
```

I need:

```
id  variable
1   val1
1   val2
1   val3
1   val4
1   val5
2   val1
2   val2
2   val3
2   val4
2   val5
```

Comment: Is there a significance to wanting **5** rows for each `id`? Or are you just trying to convert all the columns to rows?

Comment: @aneroid it should be for N rows but there will always be same N number of IDs copied down (i.e. they should always match)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a significance to wanting **5** rows for each `id`? Or are you just trying to convert all the columns to rows?

*Melting* `df2` gets you almost there in one step, and add a `sort_values` to get things in the right order:

```py
df3 = df2.melt(id_vars='id').sort_values(['id', 'variable'], ignore_index=True)
```

And then you can drop the `variable` column and rename `value`:

```py
df3 = df3.drop('variable', axis=1).rename({'value': 'col_to_fill'}, axis=1)
df3
```

The rename step can be skipped by putting it as `value_name` and then all of these can be combined into:

```py
df3 = df2.melt(id_vars='id', value_name='col_to_fill') \
         .sort_values(['id', 'variable'], ignore_index=True) \
         .drop('variable', axis=1)
df3
```

Output:

```
    id  col_to_fill
0    1           23
1    1           42
2    1           12
3    1            2
4    1           53
5    2           23
6    2           44
7    2            8
8    2           88
9    2            2
10   3            0
11   3            9
12   3           55
13   3           21
14   3           33
```

Comment: thanks! Appreicate it a lot. Please see updated question

Comment: My answer and your updated question (and the original) have the same result. The first group of values is `23  42  12  2   53` vertically. So what's the issue? My answer is not _just_ `df.melt`, it's also got sorting which gets you the result you need.

Comment: @themli If the output above doesn't match for your larger dataframe, then you have other columns you haven't mentioned or have not copy-pasted correctly.